# Devices updated to iOS 8 beta 5 can not be restored to earlier versions of iOS

Tags: ios8

I have read in developer.apple that "Devices updated to iOS 8 beta 5 can not be restored to earlier versions of iOS.". Is that true? I want to update to iOS 8 after that , I need to revert it to iOS 7 . I am using an iPad mini. is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Enter in **DFU MODE**, and restores the device by pressing **SHIFT + CLICK**(on windows) or **CMD + CLICK** (on mac) on **RESTORE** button and manually selecting the firmware iOS 7

- [Enter in DFU MODE tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bITIiGswjFI)
- [Link to Download iOS 7.1.2](http://www.evad3rs.net/2013/04/ios-7-download-install-links-how-to.html)

[image]